# Is any ubuntu version used for software development?

Tags: 12.10

Is any ubuntu version used for software development,system based or web based?

Comment: Yes, very many software developers use Ubuntu, to develop any conceivable kind of software. However, I think your question is a bit broad, try narrowing it down to what you want to know.

Comment: hi zwets, I mean that, any of ubuntu version having built in development tools.

Comment: @Vipin, There is no such Ubuntu version, but you can install all the necessary tools required for software development via apt-get as the repository has the most commonly used development tools present in it.

Comment: ok chirag thankz for your valuable information.

Answer (score 4):

There is no Ubuntu version specifically built for developers, but there are tools for developers that are easy to install on Ubuntu.

Visit http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/ to learn how to create new applications for Ubuntu using the developer tools provided from Ubuntu packages.

A end user install of Ubuntu do not have all development tools installed by default.
Ubuntu developers usually install the **build-essential** package to get access to a basic set of c and c++ compilers.

By following the guides at developer.ubuntu.com will help you install and transform your Ubuntu desktop into a productive developer environment.